# Is it possible to add a link to a specific section of another page on asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

In `html` it is enough to just put the name of the page and the id of de section.
 for example: [index.html / # products] and takes us to that specific part but this does not work between `aspx` documents or I don't know how to do it.

Comment: sorry i got confused with the spanish site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the browser's perspective, an ASPX page is simply HTML, no different than any other webpage. So you just need to grab the ID of the control and append that to the URL just like you suggested, `#products`.

What you may be running into is that the Control's ID that you specify in the .aspx page in many cases is not the same ID that ends up in the resulting HTML. This is because of the way [ClientIDMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode) is set. By default it will append the parent container's ID to your control's ID in the rendered HTML. So you'll either need to grab the resulting ID that gets generated and use that as part of the URL, or set the ClientIdMode to another option such as Static at the control, page, or site level.